# JflashPlayer in SwingNode

Tags: javafx-8

Is there any workaround to use DJNative's JflashPlayer in swingNode of JavaFX 8. I had worked with incorporating JflashPlayer in pureswing containers like JPanel. But when using java's new version- Java8 which has new added feature of embedding swing components in JavaFX using the SwingNode, I can embed JButton and whatever swing components to it, it is working fine. But DJNative's JflashPlayer cannot be embedded in SwingNode or it cannot be found working.

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: I couldn't manage to do this either. It appears that SwingNode only supports pure java swing components. DJNative's JFlashPlayer contains a SWT Browser. I had to create a swing application and dump my JavaFx components on a JFXPanel and displayed the JFlashPlayer in a JInternalFrame.